# How to build path to cover for bot if cover moves while player moves?

Tags: ai, path-finding, combat, bot

I'm changing cover positions depending of player position (to keep obstacle between player and cover point). But when my bot using pathfinding algorithms to build path to that cover, he will spend some time for moving by it. When it reaches the final destination, the real cover point will be moved and bot will not be in cover anymore.

So, how to correctly build path to cover to lead bot to right position when player moves?

And how to detect points from which covered bot can shoot to player? For i.e. bot covered by wall and he can move left or right to see player and shoot him and then return back to cover.

Comment: It's not super clear what is going on right now; do you mean that, at step 1, the bot evaluates its position, the position of the player and the position of a cover, builds a path to be behind the cover w.r.t. the player, then moves to there, but while moving to there, the player keeps on moving, so, at step 2, when the bot reaches destination, it's no longer behind the cover because the player has moved somewhere else?

Comment: You're asking the bot to make a prediction about where the player will be in the future. To do that, we need a model for how the player can be expected to move - are there any restrictions we can apply here? (eg. if the it's a click-to-move, you can predict the player will continue moving to their last click point. If it's an auto-scrolling shooter, we can predict the player will continue moving forward at approximately the scrolling speed) Or, are there any heuristics we can use to get a decent guess for how the player might behave?

Comment: @Vaillancourt exactly

Comment: @DMGregory it is usual FPS. The bot can make prediction but player can change his moving and prediction will not be valid anymore.

I can recheck cover position when bot arriving but if player moves without stops, bot will go to new cover forever.